# XPages: reading a private property from a managedBean fails

Tags: java, xpages, managed-bean, xpages-ssjs

In an Xpage I need to calculate disabled properties for multiple checkBox controls. So I built a javaBean for that and registered it as a managedBean. In principle this works like a charm: a computedField control's `value` property is bound to one of the bean's private variables using EL:

```
value="#{myBean.myTestValue}"
```

and as expected it's showing the correct content.

Next I bind my checkBox's `disabled` property to a private boolean variable calculated in my bean, again using EL:

```
disabled="#{myBean.isCheckBoxDisabled}"
```

Unfortunately this time a `javax.faces.el.PropertyNotFoundException` is thrown.

As a workaround I created a getter method which then I call from the checkBox's disabled property, this time as JS code:

```
disabled="#{javascript:myBean.isCheckBoxDisabled()}
```

This is working as expected, the disabled property is set. That's basically alright with me although I would have loved to do this using EL, as this seems to be best-practice.

Question is: why is it that a control's `value` property can use a bean's private variable while a `disabled` property cannot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work with

```
disabled="#{myBean.checkBoxDisabled}"
```

EL "translates" this to
   `myBean.getCheckBoxDisabled()`
   `myBean.isCheckBoxDisabled()` (if boolean or Boolean property)
for getter and
   `myBean.setCheckBoxDisabled(value)`
for setter.

You should always generate public getters and setters for private properties if you want to access those from EL, JavaScript or Java classes outside current package.

Comment: Hm, in fact I do have public getters (in the "is..." form) but no proper public setters for those, just private initialization methods that are called by my class constructor. So you say I should include public setters just for the sake of it?

Comment: No, you need only a public getter for disabled-property. So, in your example you would define a property `private boolean checkBoxDisabled;` and have a getter `public boolean isCheckBoxDisabled()`. Make sure you use exactly this case sensitivity.

Comment: ah, ok, so I see my mistake: my private prop is "isCheckBoxDisabled", and the getter is named exactly the same. I'll try this tomorrow (so much to learn, so little brain...)

Comment: ...and of course you're reight, that did the trick. Many thanks!